# Como borrar el envio de correos que se creó por google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Creé envío de mensajes repetitivos en Google con un código *apps script* que copie de la red y creé los activadores.

Hice pruebas, funciono bien, puse muchas repeticiones que no se cumplían todas, me dice:

> "Servicio solicitado demasiadas veces para un mismo día: email. (línea 18, archivo "sder9390")"

Este no es el problema.
Borré definitivamente los activadores, después el archivo *apps script*, creé una nueva *apps script* definitivo (envía mismo correo diario, 4 destinatarios), deje pasar 24 horas, no se envían los mensajes de la "nueva apps script".

Cómo que se sigue ejecutando la primera apps script.

1. Algún procedimiento para borrar definitivamente apps script y activadores para que no se presente la situación descrita.
2. Una ayuda para resolver mi problemática.

---

En esta imagen están las dudas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me queda claro a que se refiere la pregunta. Primero se pone un mensaje de error y luego se dice "este no es el problema" Si ese no es el problema, ¿entonces cuál es? ¿De qué tipo de activadores se está hablando? ¿Son simples o instalables? ¿A qué se refiere la pregunta con "muchas repeticiones que no se cumplían todas? ¿Se está usando el servicio de Gmail o MailApp?

Comment: No me queda claro a que se refiere la pregunta. Primero se pone un mensaje de error y luego se dice "este no es el problema" Si ese no es el problema.
- Este mensaje de error llega a mi correo, es por muchos envíos el mismo día. No es problema, eliminando los activadores debe dejar de dar ese error.
¿entonces cuál es?
- Que los nuevos activadores de la nueva apps script no se están ejecutando, son 4 destinatarios de un mismo correo. Aparentemente siguen vigentes los activadores los cuales ya los borré.
¿De qué tipo de activadores se está hablando?
- Los que trae google del proyecto activo

Comment: ¿A qué se refiere la pregunta con "muchas repeticiones que no se cumplían todas? 
- Cree un apps script a la cual le puse activadores para cada minuto para verificar que realmente funionara la apps script, llega a su limite diario, no se envian hasta pasadas las 24 horas que se resetea el contador de google.

¿Se está usando el servicio de Gmail o MailApp?
- gmail


gracias por contestar

Comment: La idea de las preguntas es señalar las cosas que no están claras en relación a la pregunta. Lo mejor sería que editaras las pregunta para agregar los detalles adicionales que consideres pertinentes o bien modificar la redacción para hacerla más clara. En los activadores, dices que son los que "trae google del proyecto activo", pero yo te preguntaba si se trata de activadores simples o instalables ¿Cómo has agregado los activadores?

Comment: Sería conveniente que crearas un [mcve] y agregaras el código a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado !!!

Por alguna razón la apps script aparentemente estaba borrada definitivamente, no se veía en papelera.
Reinstalé google, no debería tener alguna apps script, sin embargo apareció la que borre definitivamente en la papelera, la borre y tan tan.

Estaría bien que google tomara en cuenta que las apps script que se encuentren en la papelera no las tome encuenta, que es lo que me estaba sucediendo.

Gracias a https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6635/juankglezz que me estuvo asistiendo. Chequé tus aportaciones, bien, creo no es tu área. Como sugerencia para ti, participa  cuando conozcas del tema.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que reinstalaste "google"? ¿Acaso reinstalaste Google Chrome? Por otro lado, toma en cuenta que las publicaciones en este sitio deben centrarse en proporcionar información que describa ya sea el problema o la solución con la finalidad de ayudar a otros con la misma situación.

Comment: Por otro lado, de [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que en este caso sería proporcionar orientación : `Si quieres decir “gracias”, vota a favor o acepta la respuesta de ese usuario. También puedes compartir tu agradecimiento al proveer una gran respuesta a una pregunta de otra persona.`

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que reinstalaste "google"?
- respondido en la siguiente pregunta

 ¿Acaso reinstalaste Google Chrome?
- si

¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta? 
- no veo como elegir mi respuesta como mejor, ya que no hay otra que de solución.

Por otro lado, toma en cuenta que las publicaciones en este sitio deben centrarse en proporcionar información que describa ya sea el problema o la solución con la finalidad de ayudar a otros con la misma situación
- lo se y lo entiendo, razón por la cual postee la solución.

Comment: ** comentario **
Soy ingeniero en sistemas con 25 años de experiencia.
Cuando se conoce del tema, créeme que uno entiende lo que se pregunta, simple aportación para el foro.
Este me parece buen foro, espero usar y contribuir.
Cuando se pierde el control por parte de los moderadores empieza la debacle.

Saludos

Comment: Varios de los miembros asiduos solemos decir que este y los demás sitios de [se] no son foros porque en en muchos foros se acostumbra hacer cosas de formas que aquí se hacen diferente. Por ejemplo, la sugerencia para Google sobre lo que debería hacer con Apps Script no va en una respuesta, para ello está [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025). Las gracias para juankglezz tampoco van en una respuesta, lo que se espera es que los agradecimientos se vean en forma de excelentes respuestas. Se que para un usuario que empieza de cero en este sitio es complicado

Comment: En relación a la solución, en lugar de haber reinstalado Chrome se puede obtener el mismo resultado usando el modo incógnito o bien borrando las cookies y vaciando la caché.

Comment: Créeme que estas "observaciones" que me haces me hubieran sido útil, desgraciadamente nadie contestó.

En relación a la solución, en lugar de haber reinstalado Chrome se puede obtener el mismo resultado usando el modo incógnito o bien borrando las cookies y vaciando la caché
- No, realicé todo eso y mas